# font tag in textView by fromHtml() android

Tags: android, textview

Hi i am using tag in text view as follows:

```
textViewobj.setText(Html.fromHtml("<font size=\"40\" face=\"arial\" color=\"red\">ggg</font><br><br>"));
```

It makes the text red but neither size attribute works nor face works. 
I am really struggling  with this issue. 
Actually i want to show html formatted text in email body by using email intent. There is no way achieve this but to use fromHtml().

Comment: How do I use the string so that it will be in the strings.xml file? I think I have issues with the "size" part.  Also, which fonts are available?

Answer (score 0):

To be effective a font need to be exist on the device, if you are using arial typeface, it should be installed on the device, to specify font size use px with number for eg, 40px

Comment: Hi jitendra, Thanks for your response but there are only 3 fonts available on device which we generally us in xml layouts. What should i do if i want to have any other font in email. And 40px is also not working.

Comment: I don't know exact steps, but you need to download and install additional fonts by yourself.

Comment: Which fonts are built in, that I can be more sure that will work? Are the various roboto fonts available there? If so, how are they called and used?